# Change Corresponding Bar Stack Color

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

Currently I have the following implementation which assumes all items are different; in other words, there are no common/grouped objects in the dataset. It works fine.

However, I would like to know what if there are two common/grouped objects in the dataset, is there a way to change the corresponding bar color?

For example, by looking at the **last objects** of following `data[0]` and `data[1]`, these items name are same, and I would like to give same color to corresponding bar stack.

```
data[0]=[{"value":29, "series":"item1", "category":"Men", "name":"HY"},{"value":44, "series":"item2", "category":"Men","name":"NY"}]

data[1]=[{"value":16, "series":"item3", "category":"Women", "name":"RY"},{"value":23, "series":"item5", "category":"Women", "name":"NY"}]
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8mywm33/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `color: function(data){....}` and then you can use two way,

By adding some condition either like this one the color function and refer to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/machun/s8mywm33/12/) :

```
series: [{
            type: "column",
            field: "value",
            stack: true,
            name: "#= group.value #",
            highlight: {
                visible: false,
            },
            color: function (data) {

                //check if the item fname is NY
                if (data.dataItem && data.dataItem.fname == "NY") {
                    //give the color you wanted
                    return "#CC6699";
                }

            }
        }],
```

Or if you want , add the color into the data like this :

```
data[0] = [{
    "value": 29,
    "series": "item1",
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "NY",
    "color" : "#CC6699"
}, {
    "value": 44,
    "series": "item2",
    "category": "Men",
    "fname": "GY",
    "color" : "#99FF99"
}]
```

and the color function `return data.dataItem.color`

Comment: thanks a lot machun, I only worry, why legend colors are not consistent with bar color with your proposed amswer. I have upvoted your answer,

Comment: can u take another look at your datasource data, use this console.log(data.dataItem.fname); on the color function, i noticed some data doesn't have fname then it will not have color too and there is also data that is undefined